# How to check that mockito has mock the function and return as mentioned in when.ThenReturn

Tags: android, junit, mockito

Mockito - when→thenReturn is not working as expected. Same is working in the same UnitTest class. I have other function which I tested the same way is working as expected.

Following is my test method

```
@Test
public void testAlerts_whenReturnsData() {
//Assemble
Product product = new Product(null, null, 0, "-1");

when(api.alerts("-1", null, null))
    .thenReturn(Single.just(product));

//Act
viewModel.getAlertsData().observeForever(dataObserver);
viewModel.getIsPhoneLoadingData().observeForever(loadingObserver);

viewModel.getAlerts("1234567890");

//Verify
verify(loadingObserver).onChanged(true);
verify(dataObserver).onChanged(product);
verify(loadingObserver).onChanged(false);
}
```

My actual getAlerts() method in Class:

```
void getAlerts(String phone) {
  isPhoneLoadingData.setValue(true);

  alertDisposable =
      api.alerts(id,
              userManager.getNonNullUserId(), AlertsRequest.create(phone, true))
          .doOnEvent((product, throwable) -> isPhoneLoadingData.postValue(false))
          .compose(RxSingleSchedulers.DEFAULT.applySchedulers())
          .subscribe(alertsData::setValue, errorData::setValue);
}
```

Exception: Seems like it's not able to mock api.alerts(String, String, AlertRequest)

Tried with

```
when(api.alerts(any(String.class), any(String.class), any(AlertsRequest.class)))
    .thenReturn(Single.just(product));
```

//Api->alerts

```
public interface Api {
  Single<Product> alerts(
   String Id,
   String customerId,
   AlertsRequest request
  );
}
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException at .doOnEvent - api.alerts() in getAlerts
>
> *How to check whether mockito is able to mock the function and will return as defined in `when.thenReturn`*

Comment: `api.alerts("-1", null, null)` -> why did you pass here nulls? Can't you pass something like any()? What is done in api.alerts()?

Comment: @MDikkii : I did tried with api.alerts("-1", null, null) → api.alerts(any(String.class), any(String.class), any(AlertsRequest.class). But it still throws NPE. It seems like Mockito is not able to mock that method.

Comment: Can you show Api.alerts method?

Comment: Consider posting a [mre] and include the complete stacktrace. Also you might want to add some more information about the `api` class and its `alerts` method.

Comment: @second Thanks for pointing out that :). I totally missed that context.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem with the `mocking` and the `Api` itself, If `id` or any of the other parameters were null you would see a different exception. For test purposes change the syntax (or use a debugger) in your method and verify that the result of `api.alerts` indeed does return `null` and that the mock is properly injected, else the problem is probably in your `doOnEvent` method. However your question doesn't have sufficient information for me to verify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh! `AlertsRequest.create(phone, true)` was the culprit. Was stuck in the same scenario; with a clear mind & another day, you can see your problem with much different angle.

I was mocking

```
when(api.alerts("-1", null, null))
.thenReturn(Single.just(product));
```

where

```
// here AlertsRequest.create(phone, true) mocking as null. 
// But when actual call is made it creates a Object of AlertsRequest with phone as null & another parameter as true
// that's the reason mocking was creating for api.alerts("-1", null, null)
// here is it was api.alerts("-1", null, AlertsRequest(null, true))

api.alerts(id, userManager.getNonNullUserId(), AlertsRequest.create(phone, true))
```

---

```
 void getAlerts(AlertsRequest request) {
  isPhoneLoadingData.setValue(true);

  alertDisposable =
        api.alerts(id,
          userManager.getNonNullUserId(), request)
          .doOnEvent((product, throwable) -> isPhoneLoadingData.postValue(false))
          .compose(RxSingleSchedulers.DEFAULT.applySchedulers())
          .subscribe(alertsData::setValue, errorData::setValue);
  }
```

Test Passed!

Answer (score 1):

I can think of these possible causes:

1. Have you double-checked all other possible reasons for the `NullPointerException`?
   (uninitialized `api`, `userManager`, `isPhoneLoadingData` etc.)
2. A `null` argument does not match `any(String.class)`.
3. If there are multiple `alert` methods with the same parameter count, passing `null` can make it ambiguous. In this case, you need to cast your null arguments, e.g. `(String) null`.

With JUnit 5, Mockito can detect

1. method invocations that don't match the mock configuration,
2. mock configurations that are not hit by any invocations.

when you use the `org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension`.

Comment: Yes, I checked whether any variables are not initialized or something. But all okay over there. Cause I do have the same type of method in that same class which works perfectly fine. The only difference is alerts has 3 parameter which is the custom object.